# evaluation of chi-squared density

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, chi-squared

I am trying to work out the cdf of the chi-squared distribution.
My query is whether it is possible to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_0^y t^{n/2-1} e^{-t/2} \mathrm{d}t$$

Answer (score 1):

Make $t=2x$
$$\int_0^y t^{\frac n2-1} e^{-\frac t2} \, dt=2^{\frac n2}\int_0^{\frac y 2} x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-x}\,dx$$  and use the gamma function.

$$\int_0^y t^{\frac n2-1} e^{-\frac t2} \, dt=2^{\frac n2} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2},0\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, (i) I was wondering if the term outside the integral should have an exponent of $\frac{n}{2}-1$?, (ii) could you please clarify what the terms in the brackets mean ($\Gamma\frac{n}{2},0)$)? (my maths/stats is at a basic level) –

Comment: @Cybele. The incomplete gamma function